# NgIf and HTTP GET boolean response, mat error does not showing

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ng-if

I want to validate if user entered login that is already in database, for this I am sending `HTTP GET` to my backend, I got desired response (boolean value), but `<mat-error>` does not show on `true`:

EDIT: added global variable to determine if username was found

.html:

```
<!--username-->
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
<input matInput placeholder="Username" name="username" (keyup)="isUsernameTaken()"
formControlName="username" required>
<mat-error *ngIf="isUsernameUsed">This username is taken
</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

.ts:

```
  isUsernameTaken(): boolean {
    let username = this.form.controls['username'].value;

    let url = "http://localhost:8080/public/available";
    let params = new HttpParams().set('username', username);

    this.http.get(url, { params: params }).subscribe(
      res => {
        this.isUsernameUsed = JSON.parse(res.toString());
      },
      err => {
        alert("error has ocured." + err);
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You evaluate function, which returns just `observable`, not the value from it. You can't return the data from it, because it is [**asynchronous**](https://medium.com/codebuddies/getting-to-know-asynchronous-javascript-callbacks-promises-and-async-await-17e0673281ee).
You can use a property, to which the result will be assigned and use it for the rest logic

**Markup**

```
<mat-error *ngIf="isUsernameTaken">This username is taken</mat-error>
```

**Component**

```
public isUsernameTaken: boolean;


isUsernameTaken(): boolean {
   let username = this.form.controls['username'].value;

   let url = "http://localhost:8080/public/available";
   let params = new HttpParams().set('username', username);

   this.http.get(url, { params: params }).subscribe(
     res => { 
       this.isUsernameTaken = JSON.parse(res.toString());
     },
     err => {
       alert("error has ocured." + err);
     }
   );
}
```

Comment: `instanceof(JSON.parse(res.toString()))` returns boolean, so its not an observable

Comment: @janlan You return not it, but the result of the `.subscribe()`, which is not the inner result

Comment: @janlan You need to call your function in `ngOnInit`

Comment: added to `ngOnInit` still no error thrown on found username

Comment: @janlan Check what is assigned to the variable after the api call

Answer (score 0):

try this:

ts:

```
 usernameTaken = false;

 isUsernameTaken(): boolean {
    let username = this.form.controls['username'].value;

    let url = "http://localhost:8080/public/available";
    let params = new HttpParams().set('username', username);

    return this.http.get(url, { params: params }).subscribe(res => {
       this.usernameTaken = res;
    });
  }
```

html

```
*ngIf="usernameTaken"
```